# Kafka Stream-GlobalKTable join on a specific field

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So I have a KStream that that gets deserialized into a POJO like so

```
public class FinancialMessage {

public String user_id;
public String stock_symbol;
public String exchange_id;

}
```

And here's how the Global Ktable record looks like

```
public class CompanySectors {

public String company_id;
public String company_name;
public String tckr;
public String sector_cd;
}
```

I want to be able to join the KStream's `stock_symbol` field with the Ktable's `tckr` field. Is this possible? I want to create a new `EnrichedMessage` object before I stream it into another topic. I had code like below but I seem to be getting some null pointer exceptions.

```
Exception in thread "trade-enrichment-stream-0c7e7782-4217-4450-8086-21871b4ebc45-StreamThread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.domain.EnrichedMessage.<init>(EnrichedMessage.java:51)
    at com.domain.TradeEnrichmentTopology.lambda$3(TradeEnrichmentTopology.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKTableJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKTableJoinProcessor.java:79)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$3(StreamTask.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:801)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:475)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:802)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670)
```

Here's what the code snippet looks like.

```
KStream<String, FinancialMessage> financialMessageStream =
        builder.stream(
            INCOMING_TOPIC,
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), financialMessageSerde)
        );

    GlobalKTable<String, CompanySectors> companySectorsStore = 
        builder.globalTable(
            KTABLE_TOPIC,
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), companySectorsSerde)
    );
    
    KStream<String, EnrichedMessage> enrichedStream = financialMessageStream.leftJoin(
        companySectorsStore,
        (financialMessageKey, financialMessageValue) -> financialMessageValue.stock_symbol,
        (financialMessageValue, companySectorsValue) -> new EnrichedMessage(financialMessageValue, companySectorsValue)
    );
    
    enrichedStream.to(
        OUTGOING_TOPIC,
        Produced.with(Serdes.String(), enrichedMessageSerde));
```

I imagine that there might be some error in my leftJoin logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing a left join, you can assume that the left stream's record is not null; however, you cannot assume that the right GlobalKTable will have a record for matching the given key, and therefore the resulting record could be null. In your case, when you instantiate a `new EnrichedMessage(financialMessageValue, companySectorsValue)`, are you sure that `companySectorsValue` isn't null? If it is null, are you handling it properly? It appears that your NPE is occurring in the constructor of `EnrichedMessage`, so just make sure that you know that `companySectorsValue` can be null.

Also, ensure your GlobalKTable is prepopulated before any join logic occurs.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer! So it turns out that I brainfarted and the way I was mocking my ```FinancialMessages``` in a producer had an error and there was no matching records from ```stock_symbol``` to a value within the Ktable thus causing the NPE.